# SQL Reduce a value multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a value from a table that I want to reduce for each percentage e.g.

Table 1

```
ID    Percentage    FKID
1       5             1
2      10             1
3       4             1
```

Table 2

```
ID  AMOUNT
1   100

Declare @qty decimal

Select @qty = amount
From table2 where id = 1

Select @qty = @qty – @qty/100 * percentage
From Table1
```

I would expect 5% of 100, 10% of 95 then, 4% of 85.5. 
So my overall total would be 82.1 but I keep getting % of the amount, so 5% of 100, 10% off 100 and 4% off 100.

Is there a way of doing what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do recursion. This can be done with a CTE. https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/

Comment: If you only want the final amount: `SELECT amount * (SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG((100 - [Percentage]) / 100.0))) FROM table1 WHERE FKID = 1) FROM table2 WHERE id = 1`. I take no responsibility for overflow/rounding errors, which are unfortunately very easy to get with this method (this basically tries to work around the lack of a multiplication aggregate). If you want all intermediate values as well this method is probably not worth exploring further and the recursive approach is more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

The only way (unfortunately) you can do this is iteratively; which means using an rCTE. **Assuming** that `Percentage` can't be a negative value:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1 (ID int,
                         [Percentage] int, --Ideally you should store percentages as a decimal, that is what that are after all. E.g. 10% = 0.10.
                         FKID int);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2 (ID int,
                         Amount decimal(5, 1));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (ID,
                        [Percentage],
                        FKID)
VALUES (1, 5, 1),
       (2, 10, 1),
       (3, 4, 1);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Table2 (ID,
                        Amount)
VALUES (1, 100);
GO

SELECT T2.ID AS ID2,
       T1.ID AS ID1,
       CONVERT(decimal(6, 2), T2.Amount * ((100 - T1.[Percentage]) / 100.0)) AS Amount
FROM dbo.Table2 T2
     JOIN dbo.Table1 T1 ON T2.ID = T1.ID
WHERE T1.ID = 1;
GO

WITH rCTE AS
    (SELECT T2.ID AS ID2,
            T1.ID AS ID1,
            CONVERT(decimal(6, 2), T2.Amount * ((100 - T1.[Percentage]) / 100.0)) AS Amount
     FROM dbo.Table2 T2
          JOIN dbo.Table1 T1 ON T2.ID = T1.ID
     WHERE T1.ID = 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT r.ID2,
            T1.ID,
            CONVERT(decimal(6, 2), r.Amount * ((100 - T1.[Percentage]) / 100.0))
     FROM rCTE r
          JOIN dbo.Table1 T1 ON r.ID2 = T1.FKID
                            AND r.ID1 + 1 = T1.ID)
SELECT MIN(r.Amount)
FROM rCTE r
GROUP BY r.ID2;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.Table1;
DROP TABLE dbo.Table2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the result of this expression since it doesn't matter the order of the multiplication.

```
100 * (0.95 * 0.9 * 0.96)
```

You can emulate chaining the products using `LOG`, `SUM`, and `EXP` to get the desired result

```sql
SELECT
  val.ID, EXP(SUM(LOG(0.01*(100-Percentage)))) * MAX(Amount)
FROM
  percents
    INNER JOIN
  val
    ON percents.FKID = val.ID
GROUP BY
  val.ID;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/60c27/1

Comment: An important caveat with this method is that while this formula is flawless from a mathematical perspective, the limited precision of floating-point means this can quickly accumulate significant rounding errors if many percentages are involved this way. It should be used with caution.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to merely calculate a variable for a given Table2.ID ?

Then that method you used can work for it.

But tables contain unordered sets.
So you need to include an `ORDER BY` to respect the order that the percentages are subtracted.

**Sample data:**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table2 (
>   ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
>   Amount INT
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Table2 (Amount) VALUES
>   (100),(100)
> ;
>
> CREATE TABLE Table1 (
>   ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
>   Percentage INT NOT NULL,
>   FKID INT NOT NULL,
>   FOREIGN KEY (FKID) REFERENCES Table2(ID)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Table1
> (Percentage, FKID) VALUES
>  (5,1), (10,1), (4,1),
>  (30,2), (25,2), (20,2)
> ```

**T-Sql:**

> ```
> DECLARE @Id INT = 1;
>
> DECLARE @qty FLOAT;
> SELECT @qty = Amount
> FROM Table2
> WHERE ID = @Id;
>
> SELECT 
> @qty = @qty-((@qty/100.0)*t1.Percentage)
> FROM Table1 t1
> WHERE t1.FKID = @Id
> ORDER BY t1.ID;
>
> SELECT CAST(@qty AS DECIMAL(16,2)) AS qty
> ```
>
> ```
> | qty   |
> | :---- |
> | 82.08 |
> ```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c5a3a9931ac2b68454e102c4cca5ca33)*

Comment: This approach should be used with caution in general -- the semantics of `SELECT @var = [expression involving @var] FROM table` where more than one row is involved are murky (or *quirky*). The documentation does not specify anywhere that these assignments happen in rowset order, or even that they must happen once for each row. Parallelism can also muck things up. In this case the order actually happens to be irrelevant save for rounding concerns (due to the nature of the calculation), but in general recursive CTEs are more reliable, even if they're more verbose.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the review.  But well... then I'd like to see proof that with an `order by` and only a few records that it wouldn't respect that sort order.  Maybe it's not really documented, but for now I believe it will calculate based on the sorted result set.

Comment: I fully believe that for the particular data set you've demonstrated and the particular query you have there is no version of the optimizer that won't evaluate the result "as expected". Hence my remark that this technique has to be considered suspect *in general*, as the fact that it can fail in other cases (the "quirky update") is well-known and at least deserves mention. (Note that in this case the order or lack thereof is a red herring -- the order doesn't matter for the result in this case, which is extra lucky. Just *having* an order doesn't dictate internal row processing order, though.)

Comment: To see this query fail with a trivial change: try `ORDER BY ID * 2 / 2`. This is logically a transformation which should not change the ultimate order of the rows, and indeed it does not, but it causes the calculation to become incorrect as the sorting is deferred. Of course you wouldn't actually write it like that in practice, but it shows that seemingly innocent, semantics-preserving transformations can screw it up as its correctness is tightly coupled to the internals of the query plan, which is not at all obvious from the query shape itself. Caveat emptor!

Comment: @JeroenMostert  Okay, a little test [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ba8fccf0dbc205faeabf5cc61a3a403f) proves your point.  That is so weird! 0_o And it even seems consistent.  I guess sorting by a calculation really can screw this method up.  Thanks for the enlightment :)